# Radial function in quantum mechanics

Tags: quantum-mechanics

In the radial function for a central potential, if we have a case such that $V(r)$ tends to $0$ much faster than $\frac{1}{r}$, how does $u(r)$ behave? And if $V(r)$ tends to $0$ like $\frac{1}{r}$, what changes in the previous argument? I know that, for $E<0$, it has to be in accordance with hydrogenic wave functions.

Comment: Could you define things a little bit more clearly, I assume by $u\left( r \right)$ you mean the radial part of the wavefunction?

Comment: Yes that's correct. Sorry I'm on my phone haha so a bit lazy to type :/

Comment: think you might find what you are looking for here http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/12892/radial-schrodinger-equation-with-inverse-power-law-potential and links within