# Wavefunction and a central potential $V(r)$ that is singular at origin

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, singularities

I read the following line from Weinberg's [Lectures in Quantum Mechanics](https://tinymachines.weebly.com/uploads/5/1/8/8/51885267/weinberg._lectures_on_quantum_mechanics__2012_.pdf)  (pg 34):

> As long as $V(r)$ is not extremely singular at $r=0$, the wave function $\psi$ must be a smooth function of the Cartesian components $x_i$ near $x=0$, in the sense that it can be expressed as a power series in these components.

What does he mean by the potential $V(r)$ being 'not extremely singular'? I thought of the electrostatic potential of a charge $Q$ placed at $r=0$, which is $V(r)=\frac{kQ}{r}$. This potential is infinite at $r=0$. Is this considered singular or extremely singular?

Also, why is the wave function $\psi$ a smooth function when $V(r)$ is not extremely singular? I only understand that when $V(r')=\infty$, the wave function is $0$ at the point $r=r'$, like at the barrier of an infinite square well.

Or more generally, what are the requirements for $\psi$ to be a smooth function and why?

Comment: For atoms and ions $V(0)$ is infinite but $\psi_{ns}(0) \neq 0$.

Comment: $V(0)$ for atoms and ions is negative infinity, which leads to a smooth though not differentiable wavefunction. If it were positive infinity, the wavefunktion would be indeed zero at that point.

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/12892/2451

Comment: @MartinPeschel But non-differentiable functions cannot be expressed in terms of a taylor expansion/power series right? Why then does the author say that the wavefunction can be expressed as a power series?

Comment: that is true. the cartesian form of the ground state wavefunction hydrogen is$Nexp(-\sqrt{x^2+y^2+z^2})$ which has no power series at $(0,0,0)$.

Comment: Finally,what we can say?Is there any mathematical theorem ensures that what Weinberg said is right?