# Solution of 1D Schrodinger equation for the potential $V(x) = -\frac{1}{|x|}$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, wavefunction, schroedinger-equation, hydrogen

May be this question might have already been asked but I couldn't find it, so let me know if its already there.

Consider a potential, $V(x) = -\frac{1}{|x|}$ and, if we apply this to a one dimensional Schrodinger's equation, I'd like to know the solution for the wave function in 1D. Does it have a simple analytical solution? Does it have any oscillatory behavior like $$\psi(x,t) = P(x) e^{ikx}e^{i\omega t}$$ I mean will there be a factor like $e^{ikx}$ ? From the internet search, looking at one-dimensional hydrogen atom, first of all I am not sure whether there is any analytical solution, but I guess it was suggested that an exponential decay, something like $$P(x) = e^{-\alpha x}$$ is present. But I am not sure about presence of oscillations like $e^{ikx}$. Hence I'd appreciate some suggestions and clarification.

PS : I am not interested in Hydrogen atom, but in this specific 1D potential.

Comment: One possible method: A 1D Schr. problem with wave fct. $\phi$ can be [mapped](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/12785/2451) to an [equivalent](http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/12892/2451) 3D radial Schr. problem with radial wave fct. $R(r)=r\phi(r)$, whose solution can be found in any QM textbook.

Comment: @Qmechanic: the potential is the same, but the radial part of the Laplacian is not the same as $\partial_r^2$, right?

Comment: @Vibert: Right, therefore the wave function has to be redefined accordingly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

With a potential $V(x) = - \frac{\alpha}{|x|}$, with the notation $a = \large \frac{\hbar^2}{m \alpha}$, solutions are :

$$u^+_n(x,t) \sim x e^{ - \large \frac{x}{na}} ~L_{n -1}^1(\frac{2x }{na}) e^{ -\frac{1}{\hbar} \large E_nt}~~for~~ x>0$$

$$u^+_n(x,t) = 0~for~~ x\le0$$

and :

$$u^-_n(x,t) \sim x e^{ + \large \frac{x}{na}} ~L_{n -1}^1(\frac{2x }{na}) e^{ -\frac{1}{\hbar} \large E_nt}~~for~~ x<0$$

$$u^-_n(x,t) = 0~for~~ x\ge0$$

whose energy is : $$E_n = - \frac{1}{n^2} (\frac{m \alpha^2}{2 \hbar^2})$$

$L_n^\gamma$ is the [Generalized Laguerre Polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laguerre_polynomial#Generalized_Laguerre_polynomials)

[EDIT] There are 2 different set of basis functions, see this [reference](http://theorie2.physik.uni-greifswald.de/member/bronold/SS2009/1DHatom.pdf) page $192$ formulae $20a$ and $20b$

Comment: @Trimok : I have two questions. What is the 'r', and how did you introduce 'n', and why we need to introduce 'n'?

Comment: @RajeshD : Sorry, there was a typo, it is an $|x|$ (not $r$). I have edited the answer. The indice $n$ corresponds to the different possibilities for the solution. The solution $u_n$ is an eigenvector for the energy operator (the hamiltonian) with the eigenvalue $E_n$. The set of $u_n$ is a basis for any general solution, that is, any general solution $u(x,t)$ can be written $u(x,t) = \sum \lambda^n u_n(x,t)$, where the $\lambda^n$ are complex coefficients.

Comment: @RajeshD : For the practical introduction of $n$, the first idea (as indicated by Qmechanic) is to begin with a "3D" problem, that is [hydrogen atom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hydrogen_atom#Wavefunction) We know, that, in this case, energy is quantized, and the energy levels are indiced by an integer $n$. The $1D$ solution is roughly $r$ times the radial part of the  $3D$ solution, with taking  $l=0$ (because there is not angular momentum in $1D$)

Comment: @Trimok : I'd find it hard to see the amplitude at $x=0$ is zero even though it is an attractive force field.

Comment: This means that the probability to find the particle at $x=0$ is zero. In fact, we may try to think classically. If the potential is very big at $x=0$, classically that means that the speed is very big at $x=0$, so a very little time is spend by the particle around $x=0$, so the probability of finding the particle is very tiny around $x=0$.

Comment: What surprises me is that we don't seem to have solutions with odd parity. For all $n$, we have $u_n(-x) = u_n(x)$, whereas I'd expect some solutions with $u_n(-x) = -u_n(x)$ because the Hamiltonian commutes with the parity operator. Is there a simple reason why we don't see odd solutions?

Comment: @Lagerbaer : Here $Pu_n(x) = u_n(-x)=u_n(x)$. So it seems to me that there is no new solution.

Comment: Trimok : I suspect any quantization should happen in 1-D. I guess you have adopted the quantization from 3-D rather blindly. Looking at the differential equation with hardly any boundary conditions and perfect symmetry, I doubt there is any quantization necessary.

Comment: @RajeshD : I have made an edit to the answer, because there are subtelties: see this [reference](http://theorie2.physik.uni-greifswald.de/member/bronold/SS2009/1DHatom.pdf) page $192$ formulae $20a$ and $20b$. In fact, there are 2 set of functions $u^+_n$ and $u^-_n$, which are only defined, respectively, on $x>0$ and $x<0$

Comment: @Trimok : "classically that means that the speed is very big at x=0, so a very little time is spend by the particle around x=0", good one, but I hardly want to put my money on it. I think its rather dubious at best.

Comment: @RajeshD : " I think its rather dubious at best." You are probably right ...But the fact that the wave function is exactly zero at $x=0$ is one thing, and the fact that the wave function is concentrated in some interval (of size $na$) around $x=0$, is another thing.

Comment: @Trimok : $u_n(x)$ is continuous at $x = 0$, which means give me any probability $P$, however small, I can find an $\epsilon$ such that the probability of finding the particle in the interval $(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$ is smaller than $P$.

Comment: @Trimok : I am reading your reference. Meanwhile an interesting thing. The probability vanishing at center does not seem to arise in 3-D hydrogen atom. Check the wave function of 1s orbital of Hydrogen atom, it of the form $\psi_{1s}(r) = a e^{-kr}$, where $k$ and $a$ are some constants and $r$ is the radial distance from nucleus.

Comment: @RajeshD : $\psi_{1s}$ correspond to $l=0$. For the general case $l>0$, you have a $r^l$ coefficient, so the wavefunction is 0 at $x=0$

Comment: Btw, *every* one-dimensional attractive potential has a bound state.

Comment: @Lagerbaer ; (I have made a edit to my previous answer which was not rigourous enough). Yes, but this should be true for other dimensions, no ?. It seems to me that there is an equivalence between attractive potential and bound states ?

Comment: Thank you for posting the paper. It's really interesting and not at all intuitive that the singularity of the Coulomb potential is, essentially, a potential barrier. Regarding bound states, in 2D and 3D you can have attractive potentials that are too weak to trap an electron.

Comment: @Lagerbaer : Could you give an example of such a 2D or 3D potential ? Thanks.

Comment: Here is one example, at the end, for the spherically symmetric potential well: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_potential_well

Comment: If you want to continue a discussion, please move it to [chat] (you can create a room)

Answer (score 8):

One-dimensional Schrödonger equation with Coulomb potential is known to be problematic, as the ground state energy diverges. It can however be solved by introducing an appropriate cutoff. Here is the abstract from the classical Loudon's paper [One-dimensional hydrogen atom](https://aapt.scitation.org/doi/10.1119/1.1934950), which solves this problem:

> The quantum-mechanical system which consists of a particle in one dimension subjected to a Coulomb attraction (the one-dimensional hydrogen atom) is shown to have a ground state of infinite binding energy, all the excited bound states of the system having a twofold degeneracy. The breakdown of the theorem that a one-dimensional system cannot have degeneracy is examined. The treatment illustrates a number of properties common to the quantum mechanics of one-dimensional systems.

Although initially published in American Journal of Physics, as being of only academical interest, the paper has become a rather cited one in the field of carbon nanotubes, which are effectively one-dimensional systems, and where the exciton energies were predicted to be anomalously large (of course, in the nanotubes there is a natural cutoff parameter — the nanotube diameter). The problem is less manifest in other one-dimensional structures, such, e.g., as semiconductor quantum wires, since there is screening of the Coulomb potential by the electrons present in the material outside of the wire.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.