# Formation of a hydrogen atom from delocalized electron and proton

Tags: quantum-mechanics, particle-physics, atomic-physics

From the initial state of an electron and a proton in a box. I would like to find a reasonable hamiltonian, or way to describe the interaction that leads to the formation of a Hydrogen atom.

Here is the initial would like to go from.

For |e> and |p> the electron and proton in an eigenstate of a particle in a 1D box, at some $n_e$ and $n_p$ energy levels. (so $E_n = \frac{n^2\pi^2\hbar^2}{2mL^2}$,  with $m$ the mass of the particle in consideration, and $L$ the length of the box). Then I define my initial state
$$|\psi(0)> = |e>\otimes |p>$$
An electron and proton can bind to form a hydrogen atom (potentially excited at some energy level). So I would like the initial state to evolve to something like the following.
$$|\psi(T)>=|a>\otimes|\gamma>$$
Where $|a>$ is a hydrogen atom state (delocalized in the box?), and $|\gamma>$ is a photon emitted by the process.

I understand the process could emit more than one photon or involve other particles. But I would like to consider, if possible a simplified process, as I would later like to add more protons and electrons to my box.

What is a good hamiltonian to describe my evolution to the atom state?

Comment: Hydrogen atom in 1D is somewhat problematic, see, e.g., [this thread](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/69889/247642)

Comment: I see. Is it important if I am not trying to detail the internal degrees of freedom of the hydrogen atom but just its formation or not?

Comment: It is not fully clear to me what you are trying to achieve. In the second quantized form it is quite easy to formulate a Hamiltonian for the process that you want to describe, but you seem to be interested in wave functions... Btw, working in a box does not seem like a good start either, if you are working with Coulomb potential.

Comment: If you want a model problem with a bound state formation, you might consider electron and proton in one dimension interacting via a delta-potential. In any case, the first thing you do is transforming to the center-of-mass system of coordinates (basically the proton coordinates, since $m_p/m_e\approx 1000$.)

Comment: Ok, if it easy to formulate a Hamiltonian for the process I want, could you tell me how? It is important that it be in a box, I am working with the restriction of making an atom from energy eigenstates. 
I do not understand why the delta potential would be good? My proton is as delocalized as my electron.

Comment: The Hamiltonian of a "formation of a hydrogen atom" is just the Hamiltonian of a hydrogen atom (possibly including its interaction with a quantized electromagnetic field, but you can probably treat the electromagnetic field as classical). You can treat the capture of an electron by a proton via time-dependent perturbation theory (or, perhaps, scattering theory), where the initial state is a plane wave (or, a scattering state of hydrogen, but that's more complicated) and the final state is a bound state of hydrogen.

Comment: I can imagine several different problems to solve, which would involve electron, proton and a bound state, so you need to be more specific about the problem that you are trying to solve. I could just write $H_{int}=\lambda A^\dagger\gamma^\dagger p e + h.c.$, where $A^\dagger$ is the operator creating a bound state (atom), $\gamma^\dagger$ creates a photon, whereas $p,e,\gamma$ are the annihilation operators of proton and electron. But I suspect that this is not the level of generalization that you are looking for.

Comment: Alright, I simplified the question. Let me know if you want some more details on what I am looking for.